# Is there a RAID type that combines Zero and One?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, raid

Both of my 16tb RAID 0 Time Machine drives failed simultaneously last week! Probably because they were both bought on the same day over 10 years ago.

In the hope of avoiding this crisis happening again, I'd like to build some redundancy into the replacement array(s).

Is there a RAID spec that would let me take 4 drives and have two of them act like RAID Zero to create a big drive I otherwise can't afford and the other pair of drives function like a RAID One mirror of the functionally RAID Zero drives?

Comment: Take your pick https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels - but RAID-5 I think is the normal one used

Comment: RAID 10 (RAID 1+0).  But RAID 5 or RAID 6 more common. For 2 drive failures you need RAID 6, though the space efficiency with 4 drives is the same as RAID 10.

Comment: Just to note, a RAID is not a backup. Since TM allows you to backup to multiple drives, I'd do that. Create 2 RAID 0 pairs with two different sets of drives bought at different times. Bonus points for storing one set in a different location. Look up 3-2-1 Backup.

Comment: Read some of the 'related links' on the right.